# How to change proxy in selenium firefox webdriver while running?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I need to change the proxy for a scraper I'm running if a condition has been checked . However I can't find a way to change the current proxy of the running web driver instance directly, I have to open a new web driver, and I don't want to do that .

The first firefox instance was started with those preferences :

```
    proxies = [
    "104.198.10.75:80",
    "104.196.118.144:80",
    "45.79.219.25:3128",
    "35.185.3.3:80"
]


def init_driver():
    random_proxy = random.choice(proxies).split(':')[0]
    port = int(random.choice(proxies).split(':')[1])

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", random_proxy)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", port)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", random_proxy)
    profile.update_preferences()

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

random_proxy is a random proxy from the proxies list . this code work perfectly, but after that I have a condition somewhere else in my code and I want to change the proxy for it if this condin is checked, however I don't know how to change the proxy and it's port wihout restarting the window .

Comment: You could change the local system's proxy instead. I imagine that would almost be easier.